# NT groups in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, filesystems, network-security-groups

Is the distribution group or distro group an example of NT groups?

I thought NT groups are like security groups that can be used for shared folders.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no `NT Group` in Active Directory.Its `Winodws NT` is another directory service was introduced by Microsoft in 1990. **NT uses global and local groups** help you organize user accounts and simplify assigning permissions on resources.

`Distribution Group` and `Security Group` are types of groups in [***Active Directory***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups).

> Distribution groups Used to create email distribution lists.
>
> Security groups Used to assign permissions to shared resources.

***Active Directory is the successor to Windows NT.Windows NT is a directory service network operating system introduced by Microsoft in 1990***
**Windows NT is fixed and did not support the addition of new objects, AD has a flexible schema that allows the addition of new objects that allowed for better scaling functionality**

For more information about WindowsNT Please refer this [**document**](https://Windows%20NT%20is%20fixed%20and%20did%20not%20support%20the%20addition%20of%20new%20objects,%20AD%20has%20a%20flexible%20schema%20that%20allows%20the%20addition%20of%20new%20objects%20that%20allowed%20for%20better%20scaling%20functionality).

For Comparison of Active Directory and Windows NT Please do refer this [***Document***](https://www.windows-active-directory.com/active-directory-and-windows-nt.html#:%7E:text=Also%2C%20Windows%20NT%20was%20based,between%20domains%20within%20the%20network.) for better clarification.